# I can't install Mono because something's wrong with the kernel (I think)

Tags: ubuntu, apt

```
$ sudo apt-get install mono-runtime
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 linux-image-generic-pae : Depends: linux-image-3.2.0-38-generic-pae but it is not going to be installed
 mono-runtime : Depends: mono-gac (= 2.10.8.1-1ubuntu2.2) but it is not going to be installed
                Recommends: binfmt-support (>= 1.1.2) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
```

I'm trying to install McMyAdmin on Ubuntu 12.04, but I can't install `mono`. What's the problem? Should I backup the server files and reinstall?

Edit: Here's [`sources.list`](http://pastebin.com/M0qbEb4m); `sources.list.d` is empty.

Comment: `You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:`. Did you try what the output suggested?

Comment: Yes I did, and it still says the same thing.

Comment: Issue `apt-get update` first

Comment: BTW, this isn't a problem with the kernel, it is something screwed up with the package management system.  The kernel it is referring to is just an optional package (that you don't need).

Comment: Add your sources.list and everything in sources.list.d to the post please. Looks like you have enabled some dodgy repos.

Comment: I made an edit with it.

Answer (score 1):

`-f` means `fix-broken` be sure you already purge or remove or install not canonical. for doing continue you should use -f to fix your problem. such as `apt-get -f dist-upgrade`

Comment: I'll try `apt-get -f dist-upgrade` once I boot up the server.

Comment: after `apt-get -f dist-upgrade` try to `dpkg -a --configure`

Comment: `E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)`

Comment: When you get error after loop of dpkg and apt-get, you should see what say dpkg : preinst or postinst and so on. then you can manipulate its file.